# Debian 11 - GNOME: Printing a document from Firefox either takes a very long time to start, or don't print until a reboot. From another place, it's ok

Tags: debian, gnome, firefox, printing

I'm encountering a strange problem for months: printing, let's say, a pdf or a web page, from *Firefox `102.10.0esr (64 bits)`* (*GNOME*, *Debian 11*) doesn't make the printer starting immediately.

With the message "*waiting for the printer to be ready*" or equivalent, it takes up to tens of minutes before the printing begins. And sometimes it even doesn't start at all. With the surprise that, at reboot time, eventually, that printing starts itself and is completed...

This doesn't happen if I download the pdf from *Firefox* and open it with its default viewer and print it. Other applications like *LibreOffice*, doesn't have the problem.

What should I check?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Firefox 102.10.0esr (64 bits), upgraded by Debian when needed.

Comment: Once you download it, if you open it from disk in Firefox by visiting with file://path/to/file.pdf, does it still take long to start printing?